# regex to allow digits less than or equal to 10

Tags: regex

I need a regex expression to allow digits less than or equal to 10, The max value should be assigned dynamically how can I achieve this, I am using the following regex

```
^([1-9]|10)$
```

Comment: what's wrong with this? this? `^(\d|10)$`

Comment: I need to change the max value 10 using a variable
    eg. var a=10, I want to assign the 'a' in regex

Comment: I want to change the max value using a variable. How can I do this?

Comment: you *really* should not do this with regex.

Comment: But I want it with regex only. Is there any solution?

Comment: If you explain why you want to do with a regex then you may get answers that better help you. Your question reads similar to "my drinking cup is broken, how can I mend it with my hammer".

Comment: I am working in a application in which there are two text boxes , in the first text box admin will set the max value of the digit allowed, in the second text box a user enters the value I have to validate it whether the given value is within the max value or not, using regular expression.

Comment: That comment only explains what you want to do. It does not explain why you want to use a regular expression to check the values.

Answer (score -2):

I found the solution for my problem. We can Pass a variable value into a regular expression ,the following code has sufficed my requirement,

```
var name=10;
var reg= "^([1-9]|"+ name +")$";
```

Comment: your answer does not even address your question as setting a max, the substituted value is by no means a max, it is just an alternative i.e. if name was 12 the value 11 would still fail.